# How to add rounded border to the CircularProgressIndicator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget

[image: Image with rounded border to the CircularProgressIndicator]

I would like achieve the corners for the progress indicator as per above image.

Comment: I found this package on pub.dev, check this out https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator

Answer (score 8):

Adding rounded border to the LinearProgressIndicator can be done easily but it's not the same with CircularProgressIndicator as there is no support given in the flutter library yet.

This has been raised [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106134) and the solution given by the flutter team is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71085).

So here we can have a clean and custom solution for this issue i.e just add the       ***..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round*** to the default CircularProgressIndicator class.

Copy the source code for classes **CircularProgressIndicator** and **ProgressIndicator** to a separate file into your code repository and add the strokeCap value as per your requirement in **_CircularProgressIndicatorPainter**.

There you go. you have the indicator as expected in the above image.

Answer (score 2):

There are some packages but if you want to do it manually, take a look in this [drive-link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wf9-Udoun0bqmcBozz2K1B_9f8eT9lXf?usp=sharing). I did it manually. You can change it as you want to.

Comment: I guess it is real hard to use words like are, you so you have to use shortcuts as r, u etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this [curved_progress_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_progress_bar) package. Or if you want to design it manually then you can look into the source code of the package here [curved_progress_bar - GitHub](https://curved_progress_bar)

Answer (score 0):

Since [Flutter 3.13](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.13.0#:%7E:text=Add%20StrokeCap%20to%20CircularProgressIndicator%20by%20%40bernaferrari%20in%20122664), this can be done with the [`strokeCap` attribute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator/strokeCap.html) included in the `CircularProgressIndicator` widget:

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(
    strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
);
```